# Flatten nested JSON and concatenate to dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I have searched for a lot of similar topics online, but I have not found the solution yet.

My pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
index    FOR
0        [{'id': '2766', 'name': '0803 Computer Softwar...
1        [{'id': '2766', 'name': '0803 Computer Softwar...
2        [{'id': '2766', 'name': '0803 Computer Softwar...
3        [{'id': '2766', 'name': '0803 Computer Softwar...
4        [{'id': '2766', 'name': '0803 Computer Softwar...
```

And I would like to flatten all 4 rows to become like the following dataframe while below is just the result for the first row:

```
index   id      name
0       2766    0803 Computer Software
```

I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262408/flatten-nested-json-into-pandas-dataframe-columns). Unfortunately, I got a "TypeError" as the following:
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'

My code was:

```
dfs = []
for i in test['FOR']:
    data = json.loads(i)
    dfx = pd.json_normalize(data)
    dfs.append(dfx)   

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Would anyone can help me here?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few weeks not touching related works,
I encountered another similar case and
I think I have got the solution so far for this case.
Please feel free to correct me or provide any other ideas.
I really appreciated all the helps and all the generous support!

```
chuck = []

for i in range(len(test)):
    chuck.append(json_normalize(test.iloc[i,:]['FOR']))

test_df = pd.concat(chuck)
```

And then drop duplicated columns for the test_df

Answer (score 2):

try using `literal_eval` from the `ast` standard lib.

```
from ast import literal_eval


df_flattened = pd.json_normalize(df['FOR'].map(literal_eval))
```

then drop duplicates.

```
print(df_flattened.drop_duplicates())

     id                    name
0  2766  0803 Computer Software
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I got the error below: ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'id': '2766', 'name': '0803 Computer Software'}]

Comment: @Chen update your sample to mimic your question - I don't see a list of json objects.

Comment: I am so sorry I copied the table from Colab so it might lost something. I am new to CoLab. But if I printed: type(test['FOR'][0]) it did show a list. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @Chen whats in each list, just a single json object or many?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there are two: [{"id": "2766", "name": "0803 Computer Software"}]

Comment: okay then `pd.json_normalize(df['FOR'].replace('\[|\]','',regex=True).map(literal_eval))` should work @Chen

Comment: Thanks pal. Unfortunately, it gave the same error: ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'id': '2766', 'name': '0803 Computer Software'}]